# Missing /etc/default/grub/ file. Need to edit boot order. Grub reinstall doesn't seem to regenerate it

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04, grub-efi, customizer

I have a EFI dual boot Win10/Ubuntu 18.04 surface-linux machine. Clean install runs great. I have no problem navigating the grub menu, and I have verified linux is install in the efi partition.

For some reason I don't have the `/ect/default/grub` file, which should be generated. I have ran the command `sudo update-grub`. I have also reinstalled-purged grub (I believe anyway, list the commands again and I will run it).

The reason I need this file (system has no other problems, am not trying to reinstall), is because the surface has modified kernals, and I have dowonloaded one, and wish to have it be the autoboot in the grub menu.
Again grub is currently operating fine, and not listing any errors from what I can see.

Thank you for any help. When I originally installed ubuntu on top of an old windows 10, I separated out the partition on windows. I installed linux from a usb - and have a 20 gig / and a 70 gig /home and 16 gig of swap.

Here is my `fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 3.7 MiB, 3887104 bytes, 7592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 34.7 MiB, 36323328 bytes, 70944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 2.3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 14.5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 2.3 MiB, 2433024 bytes, 4752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 87.9 MiB, 92114944 bytes, 179912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 86.9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F52F55BD-D86F-443D-B197-124D7B418188

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528    796671    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    796672 215191551 214394880 102.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 215191552 291303423  76111872  36.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 496103424 500117503   4014080   1.9G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 291303424 322553855  31250432  14.9G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p7 322553856 361615359  39061504  18.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8 361615360 496103423 134488064  64.1G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/loop8: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 140.9 MiB, 147722240 bytes, 288520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 173.3 MiB, 181760000 bytes, 355000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 140.7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 34.2 MiB, 35827712 bytes, 69976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 3.7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 14.5 MiB, 15196160 bytes, 29680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I have no idea what all the loop stuff is, but the efi partition is p1, windows, random ntfs partition and windows recovery on p3/p4/p5 - linux is p6,p7,p8.

Thanks again for any advice about how to get grub-customizer / generate the `/ect/default/grub` file!!!

Comment: are you able to log on to your installed Ubuntu?

Comment: @PRATAP OP says they can. Bets are on for how long ;)

Comment: I can log into the installed system, both systems actually. Although I am starting to suspect that I installed Ubuntu and thus grub in bios / legacy mode, because on the grub screens I get a Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi , Windows Boot UEFI loader, Windows Boot UEFI fbx64.efi, EFI/ubuntu/fbx64.efi, and EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi all avaiable as well as ubuntu/advanced options/windows boot manager/ system setup in the grub menu : )

Comment: The other reason that is starting to make me think I am dealing with legacy mode is when purging and reinstalling grub I get this dialog: Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
Installation finished. No error reported.

Comment: -------------------------------------------------   How do I go about fixing this? I want to keep my efi bootloader for Windows, and clear out the grub/ubuntu legacy install (if it is what I suspect) and get it installed in EFI mode. Honestly I don't care, and would prefer to keep my working system, I would just prefer to find out how to change the boot loader kernal or find out how to generate this file.

Comment: PRATAP : no error when I run that command. It looks like it created a new empty gedit file that is blank. I have no idea how to use gedit yet btw but it opens it.

Comment: so i created a blank grub file @ /ect/default/grub -

Comment: Now I need to populate this file with a standard grub2 config with the modified surface linux name for the kernal I have installed so that I can have that boot everytime.

Comment: wait, dont create that file which is empty. when you start the system, is it showing grub? or how are you able to select between Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: It is showing grub. I have no problem navigating my dual boot system. It is too late. I now have an empty file at /ect/default/grub.

Comment: are you sure its `/etc/default/grub` and not `/ect/default/grub`

Comment: `/ect/default/grub` is not `/etc/default/grub`.  99% certain your problem is that typo you have there.

Comment: oh wow. Oh wow. Shakes head. Shakes head. It just opened up! I have it!

Comment: PRATAP thanks so much for helping me realize I need to me careful careful careful playing with command line. GabrielaGarcia has well helped me realize how careful I need to be in command line as well when I messed my system up and they helped me in another thread get this setup working. Since /ect/default/grub popped open with sudo gedit and actually has text, I should be able to take it from here with this guide https://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a silly mistake on my part!!!